# Finding max depth of nested parentheses

Tags: c++, strings

The following code finds the max depth of nested parentheses in the given string - for example, for `{}{}{{}}` it outputs 2. If the given string doesn't contain correct sequence of parentheses (like `{{}`), it outputs `"NIE"`. User enters the length of the string and the string.

My concerns: the algorithm is somewhat slow, and I don't think it's really the best way to solve this problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int maxDepth(string S)
{
    int current_max = 0; 
    int max = 0;    
    int n = S.length();


    for (int i = 0; i< n; i++)
    {
        if ((S[i] == '(') || (S[i] == '{') || (S[i] == '['))
        {
            current_max++;


            if (current_max> max)
                max = current_max;
        }
        else if ((S[i] == ')') || (S[i] == '}') || (S[i] == ']'))
        {
            if (current_max>0)
                current_max--;
            else
                return -1;
        }
    }

    if (current_max != 0)
        return -1;

    return max;
}


int main()
{
    int n, i;
    cin >> n;
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {

        if (count(s.begin(), s.end(), '(')!=count(s.begin(), s.end(), ')'))
        {

            cout << "NIE\n";

            return 0;

        };

        if (count(s.begin(), s.end(), '{')!=count(s.begin(), s.end(), '}'))
        {

            cout << "NIE\n";

            return 0;

        };

            if (count(s.begin(), s.end(), '[')!=count(s.begin(), s.end(), ']'))
        {

            cout << "NIE\n";

            return 0;

        };

    };
    cout << maxDepth(s) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if you had `({)}`? Your code doesn't check for that possibility.

Comment: Doesn't matter, in my IT textbook, from where comes the exercise, it is written that it has to be interpreted as proper sequence too.

Comment: Right, I'm saying your code currently does not check for that possibility. It would consider it a valid sequence and print 2.

Comment: Okay, good point!

Comment: But the biggest problem is the speed of the algorithm.

Comment: @hetajr Could you provide more details regarding the three different types of parentheses? Are different types allowed in the same input or must you decide on one beforehand? If multiple types are allowed, should they be treated as being equivalent or must they match?

Comment: Different types are allowed in the same input. The aren't equivalent, they must match, e.g. (({})) is not the same as (({))) (the second one has to be recognized as incorrect data).

Comment: @hetajr Then the obvious implementation would be using a stack. If parenthesis types were equivalent, then you could get away with just tracking the stack size without having an actual stack

Answer (score 5):

**Soooooooo many iterations**

You can check if the nested braces are valid in a single run through the string. Your code currently does `6n+1` iterations (!!) - and I have no idea what `n` is there for. You have a loop which does not reference `i` at all, so at the very least you could just do that part once (which would drop you to just 7 iterations), but really you should do the loop zero times. That's why it's slow. Soooo much unnecessary work!

**Wrong output**

If `maxDepth` returns `-1`, you will print `-1` instead of "NIE".

**A better algorithm**

This is a problem that calls for a stack. When you get an open brace, you add it to the stack (updating maximum size as necessary). When you get a close brace, you check the top value of the stack - if it matches, you're good and you pop. If it doesn't match or the stack is empty - it's invalid and you return `-1`. If at the end of the string the stack isn't empty, it's invalid and you return `-1` too.

That's one single pass. It will also handle the case I mentioned in comments of `({)}` which your code would incorrectly return 2.

**Code specifics**

- Avoid `using namespace std;`
- Prefer C++11's range based for loops. In `maxDepth()`, iterate `for (char c : S)`.
- When you're comparing against multiple things like you do, when you're not actually differentiating between the different values, it's clearer to just use a `switch` statement:

  ```
  for (char c : S) {
      switch (c) {
      case '(':
      case '{':
      case '[': 
         ...
         break;
      case ')':
      case '}':
      case ']': 
         ...
         break;
      }
  }
  ```
- In `maxDepth()`, you don't alter the string, so you should take it by reference to const.
- Declare variables when you need them. In `main()`, you loop over `i` so declare `i` in the for-loop itself, not up front. This isn't C.

Answer (score 3):

### Technique

The way I read the question, you are using the wrong technique to solve the problem.

A better solution is every time you see an open `'('` or `'{'` then you push it onto a stack. Every time you see a close you pop the value from the stack (you can then also check for matching braces). The maximum depth is the maximum size of the stack you used.

### Code Review.

Use the correct types. In C++ the most important thing is knowing the types. So make sure you use the correct ones.

```
int current_max = 0; 
int max = 0;    
int n = S.length();     // Does this line not generate a warning?
```

I would make all these `std::size_t`. The length() method returns a `std::size_t` and you will be using the other two values with `n`.

This is overly verbose:

```
 for (int i = 0; i< n; i++)
```

Also I hate short variable names. You every tried searching your code for all the occurrences of the variable `i`!!!!! The screen will go yellow (or whatever your highlighting colour is) with false positives.

But C++ gives you better looping opertunities.

```
in C++11

   for(auto loop = S.begin();loop != S.end(); ++loop)
or std::for_each(S.begin(), S.end(), action
or for(auto item: S)
```

This looks like an inefficient call to `std::max()`

```
      if (current_max> max)
            max = current_max;

      //
      max = std::max(current_max, max);
```

Comment: And what would you recomend for checking whether the given expression is correct?

Comment: @hetajr The first paragraph of Loki's answer: use a stack.